# What the most efficient way to optimize size of a collection of all English words in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, collections, size

I'd like to optimize the size of a collection of all english words.
Let's say https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words.txt.

It has 450k English words and is 4.64mb. I'd like to lower the size of the collection and still be able to check if word exist in the collection.

1. I tried a Trie Algorythm, but it seems to be the exact same size.
2. I tried JSON vs Array. But size is the same. JSON is a bit faster when check for the existence of a word.

Full Javascript ? Because it is used in a ReactNative project.

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Comment: Today it is 4.64mb. I'd like a way to be smaller than 4.64mb and still be able to check if an entry exist. ONLY check if an entry exist.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find something more efficient than a Trie for this.  Did you write your own Trie, or try someone else's?

Comment: What about a  PATRICIA trie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/samuelclay/4674630) for a Radix Trie implementation. He has a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jCYAw/

I saved off his list of names without the `"` each on a new line like your set of words. That resulted in a file of size ~8.34 KB

I saved off the resulting string keys stored by the Trie in the same way each on a new line. That resulted in a file of size ~5.32 KB

Not a huge size reduction however I think the searching would be much faster as Nina suggested.